# Java/Spark - Group by weighted avg aggregation

Tags: java, apache-spark

data :

```
id | sector     | balance
---------------------------
1  | restaurant | 20000
2  | restaurant | 20000
3  | auto       | 10000
4  | auto       | 10000
5  | auto       | 10000
```

i am looking to load this into spark as a df and calculate group by balance sums, but i also have to calculate the balace% against total balance (sum(balance) for all ids)

how can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the % against total you could use the DoubleRDDFunctions:

```
val totalBalance = data.map(_._3.toDouble).sum()

val percentageRow = data.map(d => d._3 * 100 / totalBalance)

val percentageGroup = data.map(d => (d._2, d._3))
         .reduceByKey((x,y) => x+y).mapValues(sumGroup => sumGroup * 100 / totalBalance)
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant data.groupby(sector).sum(balance)/(sum(balance) for all ids)